# Scraper looping though a list of URL's using Selenium without getting blocked

Tags: python, selenium, loops, web-scraping

I want to get the exact same information nested on multiple pages. I then put the URL's in a list and wrote a *for loop* to iterate those pages. The scraper works fine with the first URL but unfortunately gets stuck at the second and I get a `MaxRetryError`.

My idea with Selenium was to open a page, get the information I need, put it in a data frame, close the page. Then, open another page, get similar informaiton, append the the data frame, close the page, and so on and save the data frame as a *.csv* file.

Here is the code :

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH, options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)

time.sleep(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver,30)

# Create the csv at the good place
csv_file = open('\path_to_folder.csv', 'w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
csv_writer.writerow(['titre', 'contrat', 'localisation', 'description'])

# A list of two URL's
listurl = ['https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/horticulteur/s1m1','https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/ouvrier-agricole/s1m2']

# Loop through the list
for i in listurl:
    driver.get(i)
    # Click cookies popup
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Continuer sans accepter"))).click()
    time.sleep(3)

# Get the elements
try:
    zone = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
       EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "zone-resultats"))
       )
    offres = zone.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.media-body")
    offres2 = zone.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.media-right.media-middle.hidden-xs")
    for offre in offres:
       titre = (offre.find_element_by_css_selector("h2.t4.media-heading")).text
       print(titre)
       localisation = (offre.find_element_by_css_selector("span")).text
       print(localisation)
       description =(offre.find_element_by_class_name("description")).text
       print(description)
       
    for offre2 in offres2:
       contrat = (offre2.find_element_by_class_name("contrat")).text
       print(contrat)
    csv_writer.writerow([titre, contrat, localisation, description])
except Exception as ex:
    print(ex)
finally:
     csv_file.close()
     driver.quit()
```

Here is the error message :

```
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=52938): Max retries exceeded with url: /session/cab64f2c3688431768dfcdba1c4ca98f/url (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000021FBC3B6730>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code should work for you:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import pandas as pd

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# options.add_argument("--incognito")
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')


# # Create the csv at the good place
# csv_file = open('\path_to_folder.csv', 'w', newline='')
# csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
# csv_writer.writerow(['titre', 'contrat', 'localisation', 'description'])
data = {
    "titre": [],
    "contrat": [],
    "localisation": [],
    "description": []
}

# A list of two URL's
listurl = ['https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/horticulteur/s1m1',
           'https://candidat.pole-emploi.fr/offres/emploi/ouvrier-agricole/s1m2']

# Loop through the list
for i in listurl:
    driver = webdriver.Chrome("D:\chromedriver\94\chromedriver.exe", options=options)
    driver.maximize_window()
    driver.get(i)
    # Click cookies popup
    WebDriverWait(driver,30).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT,"Continuer sans accepter"))).click()

    # Get the elements
    try:
        zone = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
           EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "zone-resultats"))
           )
        offres = zone.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.media-body")
        offres2 = zone.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.media-right.media-middle.hidden-xs")
        for offre in offres:
            titre = (offre.find_element_by_css_selector("h2.t4.media-heading")).text
            print(titre)
            localisation = (offre.find_element_by_css_selector("span")).text
            print(localisation)
            description =(offre.find_element_by_class_name("description")).text
            print(description)
        for offre2 in offres2:
            contrat = (offre2.find_element_by_class_name("contrat")).text
            print(contrat)
        data["titre"].append(titre)
        data["contrat"].append(contrat)
        data["localisation"].append(localisation)
        data["description"].append(description)

    except Exception as ex:
        print(ex)
    driver.quit()
        
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks. I've edited this code with your edits and made some slight changes. By any chance, do you know how to append correctly the data frame ? It only returns the last result, so my csv has only one row

Comment: I have added the new code on the previous answer. This should work for you.

Comment: The scraper works great now, iterating the two URL's, thank you. Though it has only written the last results, and consequently the CSV has two rows only. But it's a serious step forward anyway

Comment: I've finally found out that the block with data["titre"].append(titre) has to be in the loop. It works perfectly now